# How should I increase pressure in a Glow Worm Micron 50FF?

Tags: water-pressure, boiler

My Glow Worm Micron 50FF boiler's pressure was yesterday reading at a pressure of 1 (mbar or PSI -- not sure which) but the red fixed line shows as 2. I had a look in the manual and it suggested that it should be at 2 too.

So, I did what I thought was right an twisted the red know next to the pressure gauge to increase the pressure but it seemed to drop (now a 0.9).

How do you increase the pressure in one of these systems (we haven't lived here long)?

We have:

- Glow Worm Micron 50FF
- Gledhill SysteMate 2000

Pictures of the components of our system:

[image: The red knob, gauge and what appears to be a drainage tap.]

The red knob, gauge and what appears to be a drainage tap.

---

[image: The whole SysteMate 2000.]

The whole SysteMate 2000.

---

[image: Small tank on top of the SysteMate 2000.]

Small tank on top of the SysteMate 2000.

---

[image: SysteMate 2000 instructions label.]

SysteMate 2000 instructions label.

---

[image: Lozenge shaped tank above other tank and SysteMate 2000]

---

[image: Valve / tap on tank.]

Valve / tap on tank.

---

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If turning the knob made the pressure decrease did you reverse the turn and see if it increased? How is the water level?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

The red knob might be for setting a pressure relief valve rather than for a filling loop valve.

I have the same boiler on a pressurised loop, it is pressurised as needed by opening an adjacent quarter-turn ball-valve (an "appliance valve", with a short blue lever) permanently plumbed to cold mains supply.

Your setup may differ, I'd try to find how mains supply is connected, it may need you to connect a temporary hose somewhere.